# How to prevent saved credentials to autopopulate user creation form?

Tags: html, browser, django-admin

It happens in Django Admin, but I assume it's a browser's behavior (though it happens, at least, in Chrome and Firefox):

When a user saves his credentials in browser, it autopopulates the login form. This is ok. But it also autopopulates the user creation form, filling the username and password fields. As it happens in Django Admin, I think I can change the template field names, but then I have to change the user creation workflow and that's not what I want.

It happens too in Change Password Form, filling the Old Password Field. This situation is a security hole, since a user can change other user's password if first user left opened his session.

Is there any option to say it to the browser that I don't want to fill a form other than changing the field name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to edit each form element, but here's how you do it

```
<input name="q" type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. As it happens in Django Admin, I didn't have direct access to modify the inputs so I'll have to override the change password ModelForm, but I think it could be the way.

Comment: You might want to look at overriding the actual admin templates. Information can be found in the Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates